# mongodb charts for date ranges and increasing numbers

Tags: ruby, mongodb, charts, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I want to save the watt-hour of my electricity meter in a mongodb.
each minute the current value is stored in the database.
https://gist.github.com/ffaerber/9473682 (1440 minutes == 1 day)

database look like this: https://gist.github.com/ffaerber/9505235

what I need now is the increased value per hour.

my first idea was

```
hour0 = Measurement.where(meter_id: @meter.id, timestamp: DateTime.now.utc.beginning_of_day).first.wh

hour1 = Measurement.where(meter_id: @meter.id, timestamp: DateTime.now.utc.beginning_of_day + 1.hour).first.wh

puts hour0 => 1234136 
puts hour1 => 1234838
```

hour1 - hour0 = 702 watthour have been consumed between 0 and 1 clock at night.

it works, but it does not seem to be the right way for me.
what if I want to refine the resolution. not every hour but every 15 minutes?

it would be best if I could specify a daterange and a resolution(minutes, hours, dayes).
and mongodb gives me back an array with the values.

I also believe the mongodb aggregation framework is well suited for?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing up the question, the dates are BSON dates so we deal differently. If **you** have a time-stamp value then do the date math as below in order to select the last value for each hour:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "timestamp": { "$gte": dayStart, "$lt": dayEnd } } },

    { "$project": {
        "wh": 1,
        "hourly": { "$hour": "$timestamp" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "hourly": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$hourly",
       "wh": { "$last": "$wh" }
    }}
])
```

To simply return the total consumption within an hour, then do some math:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "timestamp": { "$gte": dayStart, "$lt": dayEnd } } },

    { "$project": {
        "wh": 1,
        "hourly": { "$hour": "$timestamp" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$hourly",
       "firstReading": { "$last": "$wh" },         
       "lastReading": { "$first": "$wh" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
       "hourReading": { "$subtract": [ "$lastReading", "$firstReading" ] }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },

])
```

Comment: sorry but I get no output. 
`
db.measurements.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "timestamp": { "$gte": ISODate('2014-03-11 00:00:00'), "$lt": ISODate('2014-03-11 23:59:59') } } },
    { "$project": {
        "wh" : 1,
        "hourly": { "$subtract": [
            "$timestamp",
            {"$mod": [ "$timestamp", 3600 ] }
        ]}
    }}
])
`

Comment: @user310200 It depends on what format your `timestamp` field is actually in. Some of your methods point to this being a "epoch" timestamp. But if this is actually a BSON date then you have a different approach. Please clarify.

Comment: @user310200 Since you have actual dates then the edit should suit.

Comment: i get some data now. https://gist.github.com/ffaerber/9486971 but not the value vor hour1 is 1235432 but needs to be 702 watt

Comment: I need the newly added power consumption within an hour(702). not the entire counter reading(1235432).

Comment: @user310200 The result was certainly better than finding each interval. It is very simple to adapt to find the hour totals. See the edit.

Comment: your first example will output this: https://gist.github.com/ffaerber/9504342 
but your second is not working.
I think I have not yet understood the time formats.
in my db this is the last record(2014-03-12 23:59:00 +0000) https://gist.github.com/ffaerber/9504529
is this correct?

and i search like this: https://gist.github.com/ffaerber/9504721
but I get no output?

Comment: @user310200 Please show a sample of your data in your question. We are just guessing at what is in there at the moment

Comment: @user310200 That was helpful. Silly typographical errors by me and some behavior in grouping I wasn't expecting. Answer is edited with code I have now been able to test. In future do not post "gist" links and include the data in your question. This is because your "Gist" is likely to "go-away" and the purpose of these questions and answers is not just for you, but for everyone as a knowledgebase to search.

Comment: thanks a lot for it. that's what I was looking for. greetings from Germany

Comment: @user310200 Danke mein freund